# How to give environmental variable path for file appender in configuration file in log4j

Tags: java, log4j, environment-variables

I have a `log4j.xml` config file. and a `RollingFileAppender` to which I need to provide file path for storing logs. The problem is my code will be deployed on Unix machine as a runnable jar. So if I pass parameter something like this:

```
value=logs/messages.log"
```

it creates folder named logs inside my HOME directory and writes all the messages to file inside this directory.

I have a environmental variable set to some value. I want to use path of that variable and write messages under that path. How can I achieve it?

I had tried using this:

```
value="${MY_HOME}/logs/message.log"
```

but this does not work. Can anyone suggest a solution for this problem?

Comment: I suspect that it's only using your home directory as the base because that's the current working directory of the Java process…

Answer (score 64, accepted):

When parsing its configuration file, the expression `${MY_HOME}` will be expanded to the value of the *system property* named `MY_HOME`, not the system *environment variable*. There's a difference between the two.

To achieve this in a clean way, you'll have to add something like this to the JVM invocation line:

`-DMY_HOME=$MY_HOME`

That would define the Java system property `MY_HOME` to contain the value of the environment variable `MY_HOME`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you please tell me how to add the above statement to JVM invocation line.

Comment: You had mentioned that your code is deployed on a Unix machine, as a runnable JAR. Somewhere on your Unix machine there is a shell script (or something of the like) that invokes the JAR file (using `java -jar myapp.jar`, plus parameters); simply add `-DMY_HOME=$MY_HOME` to that line.

Comment: ohh ok. Thank you @Isaac for the help. So that means I dont require any changes in my XML file: Here is the code : <param name="File" value="${MY_HOME}/logs/Logfile.log"/>

Comment: Right. You won't require any changes in the code. (If you do it right...)

Comment: May I ask, If I want to debug from Eclipse, how I could pass this variable into code. I tried pass variable from Eclipse -> Run Configuration -> Arguments -> put "DMY_HOME=$MY_HOME" in Program arguments. And I tried to print out "MY_HOME" variable with "System.out.println("System MY_HOME: " + System.getenv("MY_HOME"));"   it ends up with an null value.

Comment: Put `-DMY_HOME=$MY_HOME` (don't forget the hyphen) in the *VM Arguments* section, not the *Program arguments* section.

Answer (score 64):

you CAN give it environment variables. Just preppend env: before the variable name, like this:

```
value="${env:MY_HOME}/logs/message.log"
```

Comment: This is the ultimate answer considering you are using Log4j2 and not the first version. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @vikingsteve, regarding "This is for log4j 2.X. Doesnt work for 1.2.17", even though I configured to use log 2.8.2, it still did not read from the environment variable, my shell script is a spark_submit job. below is my dependency: <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version> In the end, I had to use system property approach.

Answer (score 17):

This syntax is documented only in log4j 2.X so make sure you are using the correct version.

```
    <Appenders>
    <File name="file" fileName="${env:LOG_PATH}">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m %ex%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </File>
</Appenders>
```

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#EnvironmentLookup

Answer (score 11):

I got this working.

1. In my log4j.properties. I specified

> log4j.appender.file.File=${LogFilePath}

2. in eclipse - JVM arguments

> -DLogFilePath=C:\work\MyLogFile.log

Answer (score 2):

`java -DLOG_DIR=${LOG_DIR} -jar myjar.jar "param1" "param2"`   ==> in cmd line if you have  "value="${LOG_DIR}/log/clientProject/project-error.log" in xml

Answer (score 1):

Maybe... :

```
datestamp=yyyy-MM-dd/HH:mm:ss.SSS/zzz
layout=%d{${datestamp}} ms=%-4r [%t] %-5p %l %n%m %n%n

# infoFile 
log4j.appender.infoFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.infoFile.File=${MY_HOME}/logs/message.log
log4j.appender.infoFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.infoFile.layout.ConversionPattern=${layout}
```

Comment: This will is the code for properties file. Will ${MY_HOME}/logs/message.log work with XML file as well. Because I had tried using similar stuff with XML file, but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Log4j entry

#- File to log to and log format

log4j.appender.file.File=${LOG_PATH}/mylogfile.log

```
Java program
String log4jConfPath        = "path/log4j.properties";
File log4jFile              = new File(log4jConfPath);
if (log4jFile.exists()) {
    System.setProperty("LOG_PATH", "c:/temp/");
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jFile.getAbsolutePath());
    logger.trace("test123");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To **dynamically change a variable** you can do something like this:

```
String value = System.getenv("MY_HOME");
Properties prop = new Properties("log4j.properties"); 
prop.put("MY_HOME", value); // overwrite with value from environment
PropertyConfigurator.configure(prop);
```

Comment: This is for my configuration file. This will work, no issues with it. But what I want is to append the $MY_HOME path to the file appender path, which I am using for logging messages in my XML config file.

Comment: May I ask in this case, how I could pass "MY_HOME" variable into my Java Application. At moment, I have the following piece of code "System.out.println("System MY_HOME: " + System.getenv("MY_HOME"));"  But it end up print out a "System MY_HOME: null" when I trying to pass "MY_HOME" from Eclipse -> Run Configuration -> Arguments -> Program arguments : -DMY_HOME=$MY_HOME

Comment: new Properties(String) doesn't even exist?! So what does that could help for?

Answer (score -4):

Since you are using unix you can use a path like this.

```
  /home/Production/modulename/logs/message.log
```

path should start with /

Comment: But OP wants to use an environment variable to control the path.