# How to give environmental variable path for file appender in configuration file in log4cxx

Tags: log4cxx

I have different logs locations in development and in production, they also may be different platforms, so I want to configure the logs just one time using a environment variable.

Possible locations:
    C:/logs/
    T:/logs/
    /var/logs/

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066042/how-to-give-environmental-variable-path-for-file-appender-in-configuration-file) they need just that, but it is applied to Java and is using the Java system properties, obviously not available in C++.

So, is there a way to use a environment variable in the log4cxx config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works just the same way as in Java.

For example, in an XML configuration read with `log4cxx::xml::DOMConfigurator::configure`, containing `<param name="file" value="${LOG_DIR}/traces.log"/>`, the environment variable `LOG_DIR` will be correctly substituted. Tested on Linux/Ubuntu 12.01 with log4cxx 0.9.7.

Also see my question and the answer here: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4cxx-user/201403.mbox/%3C1378908733.20140324173531%40am-soft.de%3E

Comment: Thx. Actually I did try using ${env:LOG_DIR} as described in the Java version with no luck. Just not prefixing 'env:' works. This solution works, tested on a Windows with a properties file configuration.