# How to use system environment variables in log4j.properties?

Tags: java, log4j, environment-variables

I added the system environment value
PROJECT_HOME=C:\Program Files\Project

Now i'm trying to use the system environment value in log4j.properties but didn't set it

```
**log4j.properties**
**log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File="${env.PROJECT_HOME}"/project.log**
```

Could you please tell me how to set system environment variables in log4j.properties?

**Using log4j-1.2.7 version**

Comment: What is your log4j version?  Only log4j 2 supports this? See docs: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html

Comment: Any reason for staying with 1.x version? Version 2 shall be faster and more reliable.

Comment: For log4j 1.2.x, see the accepted answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066042/how-to-give-environmental-variable-path-for-file-appender-in-configuration-file

Answer (score 16):

This is supported by [EnvironmentLookup](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html) in log4j - 2. See examples.

Use `${sys:PROJECT_HOME}` instead of `${env.PROJECT_HOME}`

Comment: Could you be more specific? What does it mean "not able to generate"? Is it created or not? Is there some exception? What is your project - plain java / web app?

Comment: @ Leos Literak : could you point to relevant documentation on log4j?  I did not know log4j tries to read environment variables.

Comment: @Jayan See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html, search for sys:. I have troubles with their doc to get all information / syntax. You need to seek it there.

Comment: OP did not clarify his log4j version.  I edited your answer anyway... :)

Comment: I've searched for more than an hour for this answer! Good to know the differences between the versions...