# Log4j - access to environment variable on Windows

Tags: java, logging, log4j, weblogic11g

How can I access to an environment variable named "LOGS_HOME" within my log4j.properties file. Besides, I have deployed on WebLogic 11g several wars which need the value of this E.V. in order to create a directory and place there the log files.

BTW: I am using log4j 1.2.17

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296275/how-to-use-system-environment-variables-in-log4j-properties), log4j version 2 can resolve your problem...

However, if you cannot change the log4j version, you can use the System Properties Substitution and pass the environment variable: `LOGS_HOME` as JAVA System Property when starting the server (example: `runWebLogic.bat -Dlogs.home=%LOGS_HOME%` ... **NOTE:** this is just an example, I really don't know how to start the weblogic server, but the idea it's the same).