# Log4j2 environment lookup does not find variable in AWS Linux EC2 instance

Tags: log4j2, tomcat8, amazon-linux

I have a Tomcat WAR project running in AWS Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instances. I have configured the instances to ensure that they have an environment variable `CLUSTER_NAME`. I can verify that the variable is available in the EC2 instance.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10* ~]$ cat /etc/environment
export CLUSTER_NAME=sandbox
ec2-user@ip-10* ~]$ echo $CLUSTER_NAME
sandbox
```

This variable is looked up in a Log4j2 XML file like this:

```
<properties>
    <property name="env-name">${env:CLUSTER_NAME}</property>
</properties>
```

The `env-name` property is used in a Coralogix appender like this:

```
<Coralogix name="Coralogix" companyId="--" privateKey="--"
                   applicationName="--" subSystemName="${env-name}">
     <PatternLayout>
          <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}{GMT+0}\t%p\t%c\t%m%n</pattern>
     </PatternLayout>
 </Coralogix>
```

I see that this lookup is not working, as the `env-name` is just shown as `${env:CLUSTER_NAME}` in Coralogix dashboard. The value works if I hardcode it.

What can be done to fix this lookup? There are several related questions for this, but they seem to refer to log4j1.x. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22296362. I have ensured that this project uses log4j2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the CLUSTER_NAME variable in the `/etc/profile.d/env.sh`. This variable is available in the log4j2.xml with the following lookup.

```
<property name="env-name">
   ${env:CORALOGIX_CLUSTER_NAME}
</property>
```

I am still not clear of the difference between adding a variable to `/etc/environment` vs `/etc/profile.d/env.sh`.