# log4j : generate log file name with parameters

Tags: java, spring, log4j, spring-batch

Am using log4j as follows :

```
<appender name="LOGFILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="D:/direc/logs/back-${batch}-${dateexec}.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH" />

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%d{dd MMM yyyy - HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p [%c] %M : (ligne %L) - %m %n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

where **{batch}** and **{dateexec}** should refer to variables[from command parameters ] (batch name and execution time).

in this case the log file name is "back--.log"

Does any one knows how it works ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to give environmental variable path for file appender in configuration file in log4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066042/how-to-give-environmental-variable-path-for-file-appender-in-configuration-file)

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose  : am willing to obtain those variables beeing specific to the batch itself. may be getting it from its own parameters