# How to change the log4j log file name dynamically

Tags: log4j

I am sure that this question is answered multiple times. But somehow, it's not working for me.

My appender is something like this.

```
<appender name="myAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
    <param name="File" value="D:\\out\\MyApp_${output}.log"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{DATE} %5p %C{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

I am setting the system property before creating the logger.

System.setProperty("output", "abc");

Then, I am creating the logger like this.

logger = Logger.getLogger("myAppender");

But the output file is generated only like this.

MyApp_.log

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try -Doutput=abc during the startup?

Here is another thread with similar problem that may help you.

[How to give environmental variable path for file appender in configuration file in log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066042/how-to-give-environmental-variable-path-for-file-appender-in-configuration-file)

Comment: I can't use this option since I don't know the value during startup.

Comment: It looks like we have to initialize the log4j file after setting the system property.

Comment: System.setProperty("output", "abc"); followed by DOMConfigurator.configure("MyLog4j.xml")