# How to use System Propery values as a part of logger handler pattern

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I'm using java.util.logging.logger as the logging engine for my application. I want to set a system property as a part of the value of handler pattern which is mentioned in the logging.properties file like below,

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = path/${custom.home}/logs/server.log
```

I tried setting the above value, but it doesn't resolve custom.home property instead use that as a string and give below error while initializing the handler

```
Can't load log handler "java.util.logging.FileHandler"
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: path/${custom.home}/logs/server.log.lck
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: path/${custom.home}/logs/server.log.lck
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:177)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:459)
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:263)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$5.run(LogManager.java:966)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:958)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.initializeGlobalHandlers(LogManager.java:1578)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$1500(LogManager.java:145)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.accessCheckedHandlers(LogManager.java:1667)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getHandlers(Logger.java:1777)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:735)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:765)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:788)
```

Is there any way of achieving this requirement?

Thanks
Danesh

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066042/how-to-give-environmental-variable-path-for-file-appender-in-configuration-file

Answer (score 1):

The path path/${custom.home}/logs/server.log doesnt exists!
Use:

```
`java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = "path/"+`System.getProperty("user.home")+"/logs/server.log";
```

instead.
But eclipse says : "FileHander.pattern is not visible!"

Answer (score 1):

From your question I'm assuming you have manually set a system property called `custom_home` as a launch argument.  You can then subclass the [java.util.logging.FileHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html) to recognize the new pattern syntax:

```
public class EnvFileHandler extends FileHandler {

    private static String pattern() throws IOException {
        String prefix = EnvFileHandler.class.getName();
        String v = LogManager.getLogManager().getProperty(prefix +".pattern");
        return v.replace("${custom_home}", System.getProperty("custom_home", "%hjava.log"));
    }

    public EnvFileHandler() throws IOException {
        super(pattern());
    }
}
```

Then instead of installing the FileHandler, you install the FileHandler subclass using your logging.properties.

```
.handlers=package.of.EnvFileHandler
package.of.EnvFileHandler.pattern=path/${custom_home}/logs/server.log
```

If you have not set this custom property this code example will default to the home directory.