# access lo4j logging level from docker container variable environnement

Tags: java, docker, environment-variables, log4j

The variable specifying logging level is declared in docker file, and when i inspect my container i can see my variable, even when i run docker exec container_id env | grep LOGGING_LEVEL | cut -d'=' -f2  i can see the value set to my variable which is WARN.
Now, in log4j.properties file, i used ${LOGGING_LEVEL}, ${sys:LOGGING_LEVEL}, ${env:LOGGING_LEVEL}, and none worked, i can see in console logs of debug level.

## Root logger option

log4j.rootLogger=${LOGGING_LEVEL}, file, stdout

I use log4j 1.2.17, my web application runs in a tomcat container, the console of intellij shows to me logs, when i run the project, i even check in target/classes/ directory that log4j.properties has been correctly edited, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

I think your environment variable is not evaluated properly. Try: `log4j.rootLogger=${env:LOGGING_LEVEL}, file, stdout`.

See responses to a similar question here: [How to give environmental variable path for file appender in configuration file in log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066042/how-to-give-environmental-variable-path-for-file-appender-in-configuration-file)