# How do I specify output log file during spark submit

Tags: apache-spark, logging, log4j

I know how to provide the logger properties file to spark. So my logger properties file looks something like:

```yaml
log4j.rootCategory=INFO,FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/tmp/outfile.log
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=1000MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
```

And then I provide the logger properties file path to spark-submit via:
`-Dlog4j.configuration=file:logger_file_path`

However, I wanted to provide `log4j.appender.FILE.File` value during `spark-submit`. Is there a way I can do that?

With regards to justification for the above approach, I am doing spark-submit on multiple YARN queues. Since the Spark code base is the same, I would just want a different log file for spark submit on different queues.

Comment: Sounds more like a log4j question than Spark... Maybe you can try using property substitution syntax in your log4j.properties file to get the file name from one of the available contexts, `env:` or `sys` for example? https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution

Answer (score 1):

In the log4j file properties, you can use expressions like this:

```
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${LOGGER_OUTPUT_FILE}
```

When parsed, the value for `log4j.appender.FILE.File` will be picked from the [system property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) `LOGGER_OUTPUT_FILE`.

As per this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066042/how-to-give-environmental-variable-path-for-file-appender-in-configuration-file), you can set the value for the system property by adding `-DLOGGER_OUTPUT_FILE=/tmp/outfile.log` when invoking the JVM.

So using `spark-submit` you may try this (I haven't tested it):

```
spark-submit --master yarn \
  --files /path/to/my-custom-log4j.properties \
  --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=my-custom-log4j.properties -DLOGGER_OUTPUT_FILE=/tmp/outfile.log" \
  --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=my-custom-log4j.properties -DLOGGER_OUTPUT_FILE=/tmp/outfile.log"
```

Comment: The approach looks good, but sadly it did not work :(